# Why is this code giving me a IllegalStateException?

Tags: android

Whenever I run this code with the first `editText` empty, and the second and third with doubles (the same condition as within the if statement), I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
```

Why is this?  Below is my code.

```
public void pytform (View view){
    String pt1_text = pt1.getText().toString().trim();
    double a = Double.parseDouble(pt1_text);
    String pt2_text = pt2.getText().toString().trim();
    double b = Double.parseDouble(pt2_text);
    String pt3_text = pt3.getText().toString().trim();
    double c = Double.parseDouble(pt3_text);


    if(pt1_text.isEmpty() && !pt2_text.isEmpty() && !pt3_text.isEmpty()) {
        a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c,2) - Math.pow(b,2));
        pt4.setText("a =: " + a);
    }
    else {
        pt4.setText("Invalid Input");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace

Comment: Probably because you're trying to `getText().toString()` and `getText()` returns null if the editText is empty. Try to wrap each of those statements in a `if(pt.getText()!=null){ do stuff }`.

Comment: @Vucko that would a NullPointerException

Comment: Well yeah, but I thought that it can be IllegalState caused by NPE, dunno.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...
    if(pt1_text.equals("") && !pt2_text.equals("") && !pt3_text.equals()) {
        a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c,2) - Math.pow(b,2));
        pt4.setText("a =: " + a);
    }
    else {
        pt4.setText("Invalid Input");
    }